# Almacenar valor de una consulta en una variable PHP

Tags: php, pdo, variables

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
`$stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("SELECT histPre_precioCompra, histPre_precioVenta, max(histPre_comp_id), histPre_articulo_arti_id FROM historial_precios WHERE histPre_articulo_arti_id = :arti_id");`

`$stmt -> bindParam(":arti_id", $datos["idRopa"], PDO::PARAM_INT);`

`$stmt->execute()`
```

Que devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
histPre_precioCompra = 83;
histPre_precioVenta = 116;
**max(histPre_comp_id) = 24;**
histPre_articulo_arti_id = 4;
```

Quiero almacenar el valor de **histPre_comp_id** que es **24**

Intente lo siguiente, no funciona.

```
$historial_id = 0;
$resultados = Conexion::conectar()->query($stmt);
while ($resultado = $resultados->fetch_array()) {
        $historial_id = $resultado["histPre_comp_id"];
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no funciona?,  tu último código ¿qué resultado da?

Comment: Al parecer no me arroja el valor en este caso 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

- Dale un alias a la columna calculada de esta forma:

  ```
  max(histPre_comp_id) AS Total
  ```
- Usa el método `fetch` para poder recorrer las filas de resultados obtenidos, además para indicar como se devolverán las filas de resultados pasamos a dicho método como argumento la constante `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

  ```
  $resultadoConsulta = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  ```
- Si ahora hacemos un `print_r` de la variable `$resultadoConsulta` veremos una salida similar a esta:

  ```
  Array
  (
      [histPre_precioCompra] => 83
      [histPre_precioVenta] => 116
      [Total] => 24
      [histPre_articulo_arti_id] => 4
  )
  ```
- Como la salida fue un *array asociativo*, entonces puedes asignar a variables los recultados de tu consulta de esta forma:

  ```
  $histPre_precioCompra = ["histPre_precioCompra"];
  $histPre_precioVenta  = ["histPre_precioVenta"];
  $Total = ["Total"];
  $histPre_articulo_arti_id = ["histPre_articulo_arti_id"];
  ```

**Enlaces y comentarios**

- [Parámetros del *fetch style*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters)
- [Iteración de resultados de la consulta](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-examples)

Comment: Excelente, gracias